# 16.04 - lightdm - run command every login attempt and every account unlock

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, webcam

I need to make a picture with webcam at every login attempt. So i wrote a bash script, placed it in the /usr/local/bin/photo.sh

But here is the question - I don't know how to run this script at every login attempt (every wrong or correct entered password, every log in and every account unlock). Any suggestions?

Ubuntu 16.04, Unity, lightdm.

Comment: Read `man pam_exec` and prepare for a confusing struggle.

Comment: just curious: why do you want to do that, if it's not a secret and if I'm allowed to ask? and: which moment do you mean with 'login attempt'? is it hitting <enter> after typing the login password or is it when the user session starts?

Comment: @Neni our CEO installed this on his macbook and wants this on every laptop in company . by login attempt i've meant every hit of _enter_ key after typing wrong or good password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr:

It works, but some package could overwrite your config and then you're screwed.

---

I've made some progress here. I know how to run something at **every** authentication attempt.

My /etc/pam.d/common-auth:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    optional            pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/bin/onlogin.sh fail
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    optional            pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/bin/onlogin.sh ok
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

So, let's start from the top:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

Default, success equals 1 here. It tells PAM how many lines it should skip if user has authenticated successfully.
I've changed it to 2, because i've added the line:

```
auth    optional            pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/bin/onlogin.sh fail
```

So, `auth` tells PAM to run command at every authentication, of course. Then `optional` should pass script even if there was an error i guess.
`pam_exec.so` is a library which runs the `/usr/local/bin/onlogin.sh` script with `fail` as a parameter, because this line is executed when user entered wrong credentials. I've added `quiet`, because on my VM there was an error at every `sudo`/`su` authentication.

The next line, ending with `pam_deny.so`, like the name says, prevents user from access. It's default here.

Then, the same line as above, but ending with an `ok`, to tell the script that the user authenticated successfully.

```
    auth    optional            pam_exec.so quiet /usr/local/bin/onlogin.sh ok
```

All was running correctly, but… The problem was when I've tried to login to the Ubuntu's built-in *Guest account*. Because, uhm, **there is no authentication**. No password = no authentication. In this case the solution provided by @NGRhodes works.

At my Ubuntu xenial VM everything worked correctly, so I moved it to my physical machine, rebooted the machine, logged into my account, logged back to guest. Good. Reboot again - works like a charm.

So, at the evening, like everyday I've updated my machine. Reboot. Log in. Password incorrect. Tried again - password incorrect… Booting some livecd distro, `cd` into `/etc/pam.d/` to turn this off and what I see? `success=2` became `success=1` and every attempt - successfully or failed - executed `pam_deny.so`.

Booted again, logged in successfully, `tailf /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -i pam`, and some wild `libpam-cgfs` appears. So, this package (probably) overwritten *part* of `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

Attaching `onlogin.sh` for descendants :) - remember to install fswebcam first.

```
#!/bin/bash

# $PAM_* variables are described in `man pam_exec`

RESULT="${1}"                               # login result (ok/fail)
WEBCAM_DEV="/dev/video0"                        # webcam device
WEBCAM_RES="1280x720"                           # desired screen resolution (if too large fswebcam fallbacks to device's max)
FRAMES="1"                              # how many shots to take (also add nanoseconds to date in filename to prevent overwrite and/or fswebcam crash)

PHOTO_DIR="/opt/_webcam"                        # where to save photos
FILENAME="${RESULT}_${PAM_USER}_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).jpg"     # filename
OUTPUT="${PHOTO_DIR}/${FILENAME}"                   # dir+filename

# create dir
mkdir -p ${PHOTO_DIR}

# append to the log
if [[ ${RESULT} == 'ok' ]]; then
    RESULT='succeed'
else
    RESULT='failed'
fi

logger -t 'onlogin.sh' "Login ${RESULT} by ${PAM_SERVICE} at ${PAM_TTY} for user ${PAM_USER}"

# say cheeeeese (if authorization is provided by lightdm)
if [[ ${PAM_SERVICE} == "lightdm" ]]; then
    fswebcam -d ${WEBCAM_DEV} -r ${WEBCAM_RES} --jpeg 90 -q -F ${FRAMES} ${OUTPUT}
else
    # if authorization is provided by something else (e.g. sudo) do nothing
    :
fi
```

Some posts were very helpful:

- [pam: action on (unsuccessful) login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87225/pam-action-on-unsuccessful-login)
- [Login notifications, pam_exec scripting](http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the startup program (use Dash), you can do a command when the computer *starts.* I am not sure about login attempts.

Comment: but if the computer was in sleep mode?

Comment: The computer has to be woken up from sleep mode to startup/login attempt anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The lightdm.conf file supports the running of the scripts using the session-setup-script parameter (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM for more details).

If you edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, search for the line that starts session-setup-script, ensure its not commented out (the # character), append the path to your file so it looks like:

```
session-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/photo.sh
```

Security Note: Your script would be run as root.

Comment: Thanks, it's working if I try to login. But if I'm unlocking the computer or logging in after waking it from sleep - it's not…

Comment: Hi, those are different activities to logging in (both unlocking existing session), could you update your question to cover these scenarios, I shall investigate :)